# ASP.NET Validation controls prevent me from redirecting?

Tags: asp.net, validation-controls

I added ASP.NET validation controls to my form ..

I also have a static hyperlink on the same form...

If i click it , it is not allowing the redirection because of the validation...

How can i allow the redirection if the user click on the hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `linkbutton.CausesValidation = false;`